# Insert time into a field with a button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

how do i insert a date time into a field (military time) on the click of a button.

I found this, similar code, but I was unable to make it work:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#time').click(function() {
    var time = new Date();
    $('#time-holder').val(time.toDateString());
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="time-holder">
<input type="button" value="time" name="timer" id="time">
```

Why does it not show the date when i click the button?

Answer (score 0):

This will insert the time instead of the date:

```
$(
    function(){

        $('#time').click(function(){
                  var time = new Date();                
                  $('#time-holder').val(time.toTimeString());  
        });

    }
);
```

Use `time.toString()` to get both the date and the time.

More info at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_totimestring.asp

**Update:**

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cuva5y4z/

Comment: how can insert this into a field?

Comment: is there a way to only show hour and mins? i dont want to display the entire info 02:00:42 GMT-0700 (Pacific Summer Time)